# js variable is undefined but if-statement never true

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is there a different way of checking for undefined? Because a console.log of my variable locallyRetrieved below shows me it is undefined, but my IF statement isn't true...

```
Screen.prototype.getModulesPrototype = function() {
    var self = this;

    console.log('Retrieve modules content from local storage (if present)');
    var locallyRetrieved = localStorage.getItem('modulesPrototype');
    console.log('locallyRetrieved: '+locallyRetrieved);

    if( typeof(locallyRetrieved) =='undefined' || locallyRetrieved == null ) {

        console.log('nothing found in localStorage so go online to fetch it');
        var remotelyRetrieved = self.getModuleAjax();
        localStorage.setItem('modulesPrototype', remotelyRetrieved);            
        locallyRetrieved = localStorage.getItem('modulesPrototype');

    }
```

Comment: may be locallyRetrieved is not null

Comment: Try just `if (locallyRetrieved == null)`. Not sure why you need existence check, and `null == undefined`

Comment: Check my answer, but you can just check `if( locallyRetrieved )`

Comment: undefined is a keyword and you are comparing it with string. You can check by simply `(locallyRetrieved==undefined)`

Comment: what does `getModuleAjax()` do?

Comment: also which browser are you using?

Comment: and your code is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LNL7X/

Answer (score 0):

Ah, think I found it.

localStorage.getItem() actually returns a STRING saying 'undefined', so this works

```
if ( locallyRetrieved == 'undefined' )
```

curious...

Comment: null == undefined but null != 'undefined' ..!

Comment: wuut? originally the code was typeof(locallyRetrieved) =='undefined' || locallyRetrieved == null, there is an OR there...

Comment: In my test `typeof(localStorage.getItem("test"))` return `object` since `getItem` returned `null`. I'm using IE11 on Windows 7.

Comment: What browser are you in? `getItem` should return null, which evaluates to false. You're over complicating your code

Comment: interesting, chrome on MAC indeed returns NULL (so does safari). Maybe a bug in Chromium for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

When using `localStorage.getItem()` you can just check if the response is true. So you should be able to just check:

```
if( locallyRetrieved ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kC3Z/2/

The spec specifies that `getItem` should return null if nothing is found:

> "If the given key does not exist in the list associated with the
>   object then this method must return null."

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-getitem

Comment: curious, since my browser is clearly not returning null (if it did, my statement would evaluate to TRUE, and it would not be a string as my tests have prooven)

Comment: I would suggest simplifying your code anyway, you don't need anything more than the variable name to check if it's set or not.

Comment: also your existing logic does look sound:http://jsfiddle.net/LGr3f/1/. I suspect it might be something to do with your AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(locallyRetrieved ==undefined || locallyRetrieved == null ) {
    ...
 }
```